# Fire Animations from Character C++

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm new in Unreal Engine 4 and I'm trying to make a Punch animation when player press left click. I Bind the action and create a method in the Character that sets the `isAttacking` attribute of my AnimInstance to true like this:

```
void ACharacterMovement::Attack()
{
    if (!GetMesh()) return;

    UAttackingAnimInstance* AttackAnimation =
        Cast<UAttackingAnimInstance>(GetMesh()->GetAnimInstance());

    if (!AttackAnimation) return;

    AttackAnimation->isAttack = true;
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("attack is %s"),(AttackAnimation->isAttack? TEXT("true") : TEXT("false")));
}
```

and the UE_LOG shows me that is working, when I press the Left click, the value of the variable is set to true. Also on my Character Animation BP I have this:

[image]

The Mannequin_IDLE animation that makes the walking works if I bind it to the Output Pose so I thought that if I bind the new Pun ching animation this will also work, Obviously I'm wrong but I don´t know how to manage this part. BP's are really confusing to me.

Comment: Your best bet especially if you wanna setup an attack combo in an abp, is to use an animation state machine and feed the result to your output pose on the anim graph. It would be worth looking up anim instance blueprints more in depth. Alternatively you can bypass the blueprint altogether by playing your attack animations on slots through code. The point of abp s is either to give animators more control or quickly prototype animations, if you don't care about these things then there's nothing wrong per se with playing your animations through code instead.

Comment: Can you point me to some document to make the animatons from code? I preffer that approach

Comment: Documentation is pretty light unfortunately, you probably wanna look at UAnimInstance::PlaySlotAnimationAsDynamicMontage, it will accept a blendspace. Slots allow you to play animations on specific bones, and they only need to be setup once, there's a bit on them [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/AnimHowTo/AdditiveAnimations/index.html).